# is it safe to install mySQL on windows server 2003 when MS SQL 2005 express already exists?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, installation, windows-server-2003

**[edit]**
I should note that I need to do this on a live production server.  The MS SQL Server is already attached to our website and supports a 3rd party ERP package.  I want to set up a separate database that I can code against for some auxiliary pages and internal-use apps) which will be completely independent (mostly for security, but also because I prefer mySQL) from the ERP solution.
**[end edit]**

The MS SQL 2005 express db is already installed and in use, so I don't want to hose it.

Will this create problems, or have you done it successfully?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a development machine this is safe to do. The two database servers listen on different ports, so there is no problem of running both at the same time.

I wouldn't recommend it though for a production system.

Comment: Can you explain why you're not recommending it for production?

Comment: Like others have said for performance reasons. Also it would be more difficult to monitor the system.

Comment: That's disappointing.  I suppose I need to look into using the existing MS SQL database.  My main concern with that is simply that I don't want to create any weak links in security with the existing ERP solution's database.

Comment: You should be able to create a second database inside of the MSSQL server, totally independent of the ERP database.

Answer (score 3):

Aside from performance issues, assuming they're both continuously used, there shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Like Assaf said, the only thing you should worry about are possible performance issues with both database services getting run at the same time. Other than that you should have no worries concerning the integrity of the two. They are completely separate and should not have any sort of conflicts.